# "Last summer's manifestations" here refers to which "manifestations and incidents"?

Tags: meaning, arthur-conan-doyle, the-history-of-spiritualism

"Last summer's manifestations" here refers to which "manifestations and incidents"?

> I believe they have been latterly playing us false, which *may* be only
> supplementing the genuine with the spurious, but it does cast a doubt
> on **last summer's manifestations**, so that I shall probably not use
> them in my next book on Spiritualism. It is a loss, but you and Mr.
> Crookes have amply made it up.

Quoted from Henry Steel Olcott's [*People From the Other World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OMsIwSefYokC&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&dq=%22I%20believe%20they%20have%20been%20latterly%20playing%20us%20false,%20which%20maybe%20only%20supplementing%20the%20genuine%20with%20the%20spurious,%20but%20it%20does%20cast%20adoubt%20on%20last%20summer%27s%20manifestations,%20so%20that%20I%20shall%20probably%20not%20usethem%20in%20my%20next%20book&source=bl&ots=NCAha38Eb9&sig=ACfU3U2_1k02nBhMxjMwK1wZgKWJrwuFmw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEx9m7panqAhVXTBUIHbYUDH0Q6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20believe%20they%20have%20been%20latterly%20playing%20us%20false%2C%20which%20maybe%20only%20supplementing%20the%20genuine%20with%20the%20spurious%2C%20but%20it%20does%20cast%20adoubt%20on%20last%20summer%27s%20manifestations%2C%20so%20that%20I%20shall%20probably%20not%20usethem%20in%20my%20next%20book&f=false) and Arthur Conan Doyle's [*History of Spiritualism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ghqqNPvWHIQC&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=%22I%20believe%20they%20have%20been%20latterly%20playing%20us%20false,%20which%20maybe%20only%20supplementing%20the%20genuine%20with%20the%20spurious,%20but%20it%20does%20cast%20adoubt%20on%20last%20summer%27s%20manifestations,%20so%20that%20I%20shall%20probably%20not%20usethem%20in%20my%20next%20book&source=bl&ots=Bvk3C8P6w2&sig=ACfU3U1skK504X9TIyPCHrKzH6fXt7a45Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEx9m7panqAhVXTBUIHbYUDH0Q6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20believe%20they%20have%20been%20latterly%20playing%20us%20false%2C%20which%20maybe%20only%20supplementing%20the%20genuine%20with%20the%20spurious%2C%20but%20it%20does%20cast%20adoubt%20on%20last%20summer%27s%20manifestations%2C%20so%20that%20I%20shall%20probably%20not%20usethem%20in%20my%20next%20book&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "last summer's manifestations" refers to the manifestations (i.e. becoming visible), according to witnesses, of the spirit called [Katie King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katie_King_(spirit)). Apparently, a woman named Eliza White had come forward and revealed that she had impersonated Katie King at séances organised by Jennie and Nelson Holmes.

"They" in "they have been latterly playing us false" refers to the Holmeses and the impersonation mentioned above.